# How do you define arrays of different sizes using if statements in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, scope, variable-declaration

So, I was trying to code some test cases for a Java project I'm doing, and I decided that I wanted to move them into a function of their own, and choose between them using a parameter of the test function, rather than just using commenting and uncommenting of code, as I'm currently doing. However, I hit a snag: the code in question involves the initialisation of array variables, and if I try to initialise them inside an if-else statement, then the other pieces of code later on aren't capable of seeing them due to scope issues. Additionally, in Java, arrays are of a fixed size, and some of the test cases involve arrays of different sizes (including empty arrays), so simply creating the array before hand doesn't work.

Here's the code I've already tried (with arrayGen being a function that creates an integer array of n elements, with pseudorandom values that lie between the lower and upper bounds, inclusive). Note that in order to change which test case I'm running, I need to comment out the current test case and uncomment the test case I want to run; I'd like to replace this with a series of if-else if-else statements if possible.

```
    System.out.println("Unsorted:");
    int[] unsorted = arrayGen(n,lower,upper);
    //sorted array:
    //int[] unsorted = new int[n];
    //for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    //{
    //    if (lower+i<upper)
    //    {
    //        unsorted[i]=lower+i;
    //    }
    //    else unsorted[i]=upper;
    //}
    //reverse sorted array:
    //int[] unsorted = new int[n];
    //for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    //{
    //    if (upper-i>lower)
    //    {
    //        unsorted[i]=upper-i;
    //    }
    //    else unsorted[i]=lower;
    //}
    //array of static numbers:
    //int[] unsorted = arrayGen(n,upper,upper);
    //empty array:
    //int[] unsorted = arrayGen(0,lower,upper);
```

Is there any way to fix this, and have a neater version of my code, or am I going to have to be stuck with just commenting and uncommenting the test cases I want to use?

Comment: Learn to use either JUnit or TestNG.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem If you'd like to explain how they would help me, feel free to post how they'd help in the answers. This is a legitimate question, and as far as I could tell it hadn't been asked before; I'm not sure why it's getting downvoted.

Comment: @nick012000 I don't see any code only comments... I did not understand what exactly is your problem as what you've described as a problem just requires a better technique to get over it... As of tests -> use any Test framework and then use google to find any, and again use google to find resources on learning any...

Comment: Testing frameworks like JUnit are specifically designed to help test code. Since you're asking about testing code, they seem relevant.

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote you (although I will downvote any answer that doesn't use a testing framework) so I can't comment on why you've been downvoted.  But if you look for the web sites relating to JUnit or TestNG, you'll find tutorials you can follow.  There's not a whole lot of point in my reproducing all that kind of material here.  I've told you what to google.

Comment: @dbl My code is in the comments - in order to change the test case, I need to comment out the current test case, and uncomment out the test case I want to change to.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking. If you write automated tests, you should use a testing framework. Even without that, why not have a separate method for each test that can be run independently? You can then choose which of these methods to call (testing frameworks have tools for that) -- but why not just run all of them all the time, they don't seem to take a lot of time.

Comment: @Thilo Because the code I've just shown you is just the test case generation, and the tests themselves print dozens of lines to the console. I only want to run one test at a time, and to switch between them manually.

Comment: Usually, automated tests come with automated assertions, and there is no need to look at console output (unless something failed). And each test case includes both the case generation and the matching expected result / assertions. So you can just run the test and look at the total result (which again, will be nicely reported by test frameworks). `24 tests run / 23 passed / 1 failed ("testSortingNegativeNumbers")`

Comment: @Thilo I'm testing performance/Big O efficiency classes of sorting algorithms as well as edge case performance, and the number of basic operations that the algorithms as well as the contents of the sorted and unsorted arrays are printed to the console for manual verification that the sorted output was correct.

Comment: I don't see the need for manual verification to check if sorting is correct, but okay ... Either way, you can have functions that return the `unsorted` test case data that you want, and then choose one of those by some parameter. Conditional execution is a thing. You do not need to comment out code and re-compile.
`int[] unsorted; if (x) unsorted = callX() else if (y) unsorted = callY() else unsorted = callZ();`

Comment: @Thilo If you can tell me how to create a single function that can do that, so that I just need to change a parameter of it to alter the test case data it outputs, feel free to post it in the answers because that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @nick012000 The answer to your question is contained in ANY tutorial on JUnit or TestNG.  There's no point in asking others to provide what you can easily find for yourself.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I googled, looking for how to use JUnit to generate variably-sized arrays and I found literally nothing that appeared to be helpful for solving this problem, including the JUnit documentation itself. I found some stuff talking about how to iterate through lists of strings, but nothing about what I'm asking about here. If you want to explain *how* to use JUnit to solve this problem, feel free to do so in the answers.

Comment: How to generate a variably-sized array (with different contents according to input parameters) is a basic Java question and has nothing to do with JUnit (or any other library). All we are saying is that you should use JUnit to help organizing your test code (such as being able to define multiple test cases, control which are being run, and get nice reporting of the results)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can give you an idea.

```
int[] unsorted = makeTestData("random");

private int[] makeTestData(String type, int n, int lower, int upper){
  switch(type){
    case "random":  return arrayGen(n,lower,upper);
    case "static":  return arrayGen(n, upper, upper);
    case "empty":   return new int[0];
    case "sorted":
       int[] toSort = arrayGen(n, lower, upper);
       Arrays.sort(toSort);
       return toSort;
    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException(type);
   }
}
```

If you run into scoping issues about re-defined variables, try moving things into their own self-contained functions.

But seriously, try using one of the established testing frameworks like JUnit. They give you a lot of the "boilerplate" stuff to run and report on tests for free.